# No message body writer has been found for response class MyException

Tags: jax-rs

I'm using Apache-cxf to implement Restful web services. I'm using ExceptionMapper to build the response object in case if exception occurs. I'm getting below error if any exception occurs.

"No message body writer has been found for response class MyException."

I could find some of the post which suggest to custom Writer which implements MessageBodyWriter, but i'm not very clear why do i need a custom writer if entity object (ErrorInfo) which is passed for building response is the jaxb object. This might be a very silly question but just want to understand.

```
@Provider
public class MyExceptionMapper implements
    ExceptionMapper<MyException> {

@Override
public Response toResponse(MyException ex) {
    Response.Status statusCode = exceptionMap.get(ex.getClass());
    ErrorInfo errorInfo=new ErrorInfo();
    errorInfo.setErrorCode(ex.getErrorCode());
    errorInfo.setErrorMessage(ex.getMessage());

    return Response.status(statusCode).entity(ex).build();
    }
}


@XmlRootElement(name = "errorInfo")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "errorCode", "errorMessage"})
public class ErrorInfo {
private String errorCode;
private String errorMessage;


public String getErrorCode() {
    return errorCode;
}
public void setErrorCode(String errorCode) {
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
}
public String getErrorMessage() {
    return errorMessage;
}
public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
}
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Had the same problem, for me setting the content type explicitly solved the issue:

```
return Response.status(statusCode).entity(ex).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
```